# Pointing Custom Domain to Server on Nginx

Tags: nginx, azure, ruby-on-rails, cname-record, phusion-passenger

I have my server up and running on an Azure Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine. It is working great. Now I want to point my custom domain to it so that users can visit my website by going to www.example.com instead of www.example.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com.

I changed the DNS settings on my domain registrar by setting a CNAME with the following settings:

**Name:** www

**Value:** example.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com

My website at www.example.com is showing the "Welcome to nginx on Ubuntu!" configuration page, while my Azure domain is correctly showing my application. Here's my Nginx configuration (I'm using Passenger with Rails):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/example/code/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /home/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby;
}
```

I've done a lot of searching and can't seem to find out what's missing. I thought that changing the CNAME in my DNS settings would be enough to get this to work.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Alfred. This has been resolved (see answer below), but I didn't find any errors in the logs. The access logs showed that my site was being accessed, although it wasn't serving the correct page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `server_name` needs to match the `CNAME` record you created, not the target of the `CNAME`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I set the server name as such: `server_name example.com;` Now I'm getting the Nginx configuration page on both domains.

Comment: Then you didn't follow my recommendations. The CNAME you created was `www.example.com`, not `example.com`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked great! I thought I just needed to specify the value of the CNAME record, so thank you for the clarification!

Comment: No problem. It would probably do you well to read up on [name-based virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based) so you understand what actually is going on under the hood. It's not complicated.