# Publicly sharing nginx configuration - is it OK?

Tags: nginx, security

I'm new to nginx and I wanted to share the configuration I have created with others for feedback; from a security perspective, assuming the rest of my server is appropriately secured and up to date, is it ok to share my nginx config? Post it publically?

I used this command to create a concatenated version of the various config fragments:

```
tail -n +1 *.conf conf.d/*.conf sites-enabled/*.conf &> /home/ubuntu/nginx.txt
```

I've gone through the file and tried to identify any potential security flaws:

- Good: there are no SSL certificates/keys embedded
- Bad?: there are paths to various folders (e.g. where the SSL cert is)

  - but these are all pretty standard paths...
- Bad?: there are public IPs and domains - should they be redacted?
- Bad?: The list of `ssl_ciphers` we accept are included... but this could be discovered anyway?
- Unknown: Are there any other settings that shouldn't be published (like `client_max_body_size` - maybe that could be exploited by sending large payloads?)

I understand that an aspect of security is simply not sharing information that doesn't need to be shared but assuming you need help, what and how much of your config would you share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you would need to share your entire Nginx configuration for feedback on security. You could talk more broadly about the concepts, just as you did in your post. If you do post your Nginx configuration, it shouldn't be too big a concern unless you're exposing critical information. But it's always better to replace your specific information with placeholder information to ensure you don't reveal anything that could be exploited or used. I posted for help on Nginx months ago; you can take a look at what I did here: [Pointing Custom Domain to Server on Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/754500/pointing-custom-domain-to-server-on-nginx). I posted only the part of the config that was relevant to my question.

With regards to your specific questions:

- Bad?: there are paths to various folders (e.g. where the SSL cert is)
  but these are all pretty standard paths...

This wouldn't be that harmful to publish since someone would need access to your machine, but again it's better to be safer. Replace the paths with something more generic like `~/my_cert.pem`. You also don't have to include every SSL cert path. If you're handling one of them correctly, then you should apply the same practices to the others.

- Bad?: there are public IPs and domains - should they be redacted?

Same deal here. Replace your IP with something generic like "127.0.0.1" and your domain with "www.example.com." Anyone helping you will not need to know your exact domain name.

- Bad?: The list of ssl_ciphers we accept are included... but this could be discovered anyway?

I don't think this would be of concern since ciphers are publicly available and by their nature do not compromise encryption without someone having your private key.

In general, it's good practice not to reveal any application- or server-specific information. Anyone helping you will not need it, anyway, especially for Nginx configuration.

Comment: To clarify: there's nothing fatally wrong with sharing a full nginx config, you should just remove specifics as good practice?

Comment: Yes, great summary!